# Volume limit specific app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, volume-control, spotify

Is there an app that will let me set a maximum volume on JUST Spotify? Spotify at 100% is a LOT louder than YouTube at 100%. I **never** want to listen to Spotify at 100%, but occasionally I do want to do so for a YouTube video.

I'm asking because a few times, I've accidentally pressed and held the volume up button when listening to Spotify--I think I may have already seriously damaged my hearing that way.

Comment: Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShg1iOakOQ) that will show you how to set the volume per app. It uses the [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) app to do this.

Answer (score -1):

[Volume Limiter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vrz.volume)

I stumbled upon your question googling the same thing

Comment: I've tried that app... unfortunately, it doesn't really limit the volume; it lets it go as high as you push it and then forces it back down a couple seconds later. Thanks though!

Comment: Can you expand on your answer here? How does this app solve the problem?