# How to lower down the volume more than by default?

Tags: calls, volume-control

When receiving calls, I sometime use the default headphone but the sound is too high for me.

I set the volume to the lower, but it's still too high.

How can I define the volume lower than the limited default from android, and if yes, how ?

Info : I don't have a volume parameter on my headphone
Info 2 : It's a HTC One S (not One, One S !)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce minimum in call volume](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5154/16575)? See also: [Volume limit specific app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43243/16575) / [Minimum volume is too high with headphones](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16313/16575)